# How do I replace the values in the second dataframe based on the values in the first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes i.e df and df1,

`df`:

```
Product_name     Name        City
Rice             Chetwynd    Chetwynd, British Columbia, Canada
Wheat            Yuma        Yuma, AZ, United States
Sugar            Dochra      Singleton, New South Wales, Australia
Milk             India       Hyderabad, India
```

`df1`:

```
Product_ID Unique_ID Origin_From Deliver_To
231        125         Sugar         Milk
598        125         Milk          Wheat
786        125         Rice          Sugar    
568        125         Sugar         Wheat
122        125         Wheat         Rice
269        125         Milk          Wheat
```

Final Output (df2): Get the values of `"Origin_From"` and `"Deliver_To"` values in `df1` then search each values in `df`, if found then replace `"Origin_From"` and `"Deliver_To"` values in `df1` with `df[city] + df[Origin_From/Origin_To]`. output (df2) would be something like below.

df2:

```
Product_ID  unique_ID   Origin_From                                         Deliver_To
231         125         Singleton, New South Wales, Australia, (Sugar)      Hyderabad, India, (Milk)
598         125         Hyderabad, India, (Milk)                            Yuma, AZ, United States, (Wheat)
786         125         Chetwynd, British Columbia, Canada, (Rice)          Singleton, New South Wales, Australia, (Sugar)
568         125         Singleton, New South Wales, Australia, (Sugar)      Yuma, AZ, United States, (Wheat)
122         125         Yuma, AZ, United States, (Wheat)                    Chetwynd, British Columbia, Canada, (Rice)
269         125         Hyderabad, India, (Milk)                            Yuma, AZ, United States, (Wheat)
```

I am struggling a bit with it so a couple of shoves in the right direction would really help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you do`Origin_From/Origin_To` is that division or "one of these"?  If it doesn't mean division this seems pretty strait forward, what did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen: Not a division it is like df[city] + df[Origin_From] and df[city] + df[Origin_To]. Thanks

Comment: @piRSquared: I have tried with simple for loop and search the each pattern and replace with df['City'] + "," + "( " + df['Code'] + " )". It takes more time to execute if the file size is huge. Pls let me know can it be possible by using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Setup

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df_txt = """Product_name     Name        City
Rice             Chetwynd    Chetwynd, British Columbia, Canada
Wheat            Yuma        Yuma, AZ, United States
Sugar            Dochra      Singleton, New South Wales, Australia
Milk             India       Hyderabad, India"""

df1_txt = """Product_ID  Unique_ID  Origin_From  Deliver_To
231        125         Sugar         Milk
598        125         Milk          Wheat
786        125         Rice          Sugar    
568        125         Sugar         Wheat
122        125         Wheat         Rice
269        125         Milk          Wheat"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_txt), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df1_txt), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')
```

---

## Solution

***option 1***

```
m = df.set_index('Product_name').City

df2 = df1.copy()
df2.Origin_From = df1.Origin_From.map(m) + ', (' + df1.Origin_From + ')'
df2.Deliver_To = df1.Deliver_To.map(m)+ ', (' + df1.Deliver_To + ')'

df
```

***option 2***

```
m = df.set_index('Product_name').City

c = ['Origin_From', 'Deliver_To']
fnt = df1[c].stack()
df2 = df1.drop(c, 1).join(fnt.map(m).add(fnt.apply(', ({})'.format)).unstack())
```

***option 3***
using `merge`

```
c = ['Origin_From', 'Deliver_To']
ds = df1[c].stack().to_frame('Product_name')
ds['City'] = ds.merge(df)['City'].values

df2 = df1.drop(c, 1).join(ds.City.add(', (').add(ds.Product_name).add(')').unstack())
```

[image]

---

***Deeper explanation of option 3***

- assign the target columns to variable `c` for convenience
- use `stack` to convert 2-column dataframe into a series object with a multi-index
- anticipating that I'm going to merge, I use `to_frame` to convert the series object into a single column dataframe.  `pd.merge` only works on dataframes`
- more anticipation, I pass the name of the single column to the `to_frame` method.  This is be a coincident column name that will be merged on.
- add a column named `'City'` that is the results of the merge.  I add the values to the column with the `values` attribute in order to ignore the index of the resulting merge and focus on just the resulting values.
- `ds` now has the index I want in it's first level.  I leave stacked while I do some convenient string operations, then I `unstack`.  In this form, the indices are aligned and a can leverage `join`

I hope that's clear.

Comment: Thanks, piRSquared! I tried with your first solution it worked for me. If possible can you please explain me the last solution (3) as I am interested to implement in pandas.